# How to get parameter types using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I want to use functions having different numbers of parameters.  The problem is that I don't know the number of parameters of each function, and also I don't know names of function as they are stored in an array.  I only knows the class name, but don't want to use `getDeclaredMethods` as it will increase search time.  Is there a way to get the parameter types for each function?

Comment: *as they are stored in an array* who's 'they'? The methods or the parameters? please show some code to illustrate that

Comment: I don't really understand how using "getDeclaredMethods" would "increase search time" ... what you want are the parameter types of all methods right? Then you'll have to iterate over all methods anyway IIUC...

Comment: getDeclaredMethods caches the results it gets so there is not much performance hit for repeatedly calling this on a class.

Comment: I think this question is very vague. Please clarify the question and preferably add relevant code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: If you want "get the parameter types for each function", you need to use getDeclaredMethods. This is the essence of "for each function"!

Comment: @Abhinav Why do you have such setup? If you tell us what are you trying to do, we can maybe help you code it better. Have you considered using varargs?

Answer (score 4):

What I usually do when I have to look up methods is to generate a cache key from the query I am doing and save the search result with this cache key in a map.

Example:

I know the method parameters are `Boolean.TRUE`, `Arrays.asList("foo","bar","baz")` and `BigInteger.valueOf(77777l)`

My class contains a method with the signature

```
public foo(boolean, Collection, Number)
```

There's no way I can directly map the parameters to the parameter types because I just don't know which of the super classes or interfaces is the parameter type as you can see from the following table:

```
Expected Type          |  What I have
-----------------------------------------------------
 boolean               |  java.lang.Boolean
 java.util.Collection  |  java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
 java.lang.Number      |  java.math.BigInteger
```

Each of these pairs is compatible, but there's no way to find the compatible method without defining a comparison method, something like this:

```
// determine whether a method's parameter types are compatible
// with my arg array
public static boolean isCompatible(final Method method,
    final Object[] params) throws Exception{
    final Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
    if(params.length != parameterTypes.length){
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
        final Object object = params[i];
        final Class<?> paramType = parameterTypes[i];
        if(!isCompatible(object, paramType)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// determine whether a single object is compatible with
// a single parameter type
// careful: the object may be null
private static boolean isCompatible(final Object object,
    final Class<?> paramType) throws Exception{
    if(object == null){
        // primitive parameters are the only parameters
        // that can't handle a null object
        return !paramType.isPrimitive();
    }
    // handles same type, super types and implemented interfaces
    if(paramType.isInstance(object)){
        return true;
    }
    // special case: the arg may be the Object wrapper for the
    // primitive parameter type
    if(paramType.isPrimitive()){
        return isWrapperTypeOf(object.getClass(), paramType);
    }
    return false;

}

/*
  awful hack, can be made much more elegant using Guava:

  return Primitives.unwrap(candidate).equals(primitiveType);

*/
private static boolean isWrapperTypeOf(final Class<?> candidate,
    final Class<?> primitiveType) throws Exception{
    try{
        return !candidate.isPrimitive()
            && candidate
                .getDeclaredField("TYPE")
                .get(null)
                .equals(primitiveType);
    } catch(final NoSuchFieldException e){
        return false;
    } catch(final Exception e){
        throw e;
    }
}
```

So what I'd do is have a method cache:

```
private static final Map<String, Set<Method>> methodCache;
```

and add a lookup method like this:

```
public static Set<Method> getMatchingMethods(final Class<?> clazz,
    final Object[] args) throws Exception{
    final String cacheKey = toCacheKey(clazz, args);
    Set<Method> methods = methodCache.get(cacheKey);
    if(methods == null){
        final Set<Method> tmpMethods = new HashSet<Method>();
        for(final Method candidate : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()){
            if(isCompatible(candidate, args)){
                tmpMethods.add(candidate);
            }
        }
        methods = Collections.unmodifiableSet(tmpMethods);
        methodCache.put(cacheKey, methods);
    }
    return methods;
}

private static String toCacheKey(final Class<?> clazz, final Object[] args){
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(clazz.getName());
    for(final Object obj : args){
        sb.append('-').append(
            obj == null ? "null" : obj.getClass().getName());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

That way, subsequent lookups will take much less time than the first one (for parameters of the same type).

Of course since `Class.getDeclaredMethods()` uses a cache internally, the question is whether my cache improves performance at all. It's basically a question of what's faster:

1. generating a cache key and querying a HashMap or
2. iterating over all methods and querying for parameter compatibility

My guess: for large classes (many methods), the first method will win, otherwise the second will