# Java. How can I upcast type use reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a two classes UpObj and DownObj

```
public class UpObj {

    public UpObj() {
        System.out.println("Load UpObj ");
    }

}

public class DownObj extends UpObj {

    public DownObj() {
        System.out.println("Load DownObj ");
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Caller {

    UpObj obj;

    public Caller(UpObj obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
        System.out.println("!!!");
    }

}
```

---

```
public class GNUMakeFile {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DownObj iView = new DownObj();
        Class<?> iViewClass = iView.getClass();
        Class<?> clazz;
        try {
            clazz = Class.forName("bla.bla.bla.Caller");
            Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(iViewClass);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

So, I want upcast my child type DownObj to parent UpObj in Caller constructor.
I think this is possible with help generics. Something like this . 
Anybody know how exactly this use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way doing it. Try to google for some solutions, e.g. http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1329/ or [How to get parameter types using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967575/how-to-get-parameter-types-using-reflection) . As I remember the Spring and some other libraries have similar util functions to do it. Do you use the Spring?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be using `Class.getConstructor()` with the runtime type of what you want to pass to it – the method works off the formal parameters.

If you need to search for a constructor that matches some objects that you have, you'll have to loop over [`getConstructors()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors%28%29), inspect the formal parameters of each constructor, and check whether you found a suitable signature using [`Class.isAssignableFrom()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29). I don't think there's a convenient way to have the reflection API do overload resolution for you.

(Alternatively, rethink your approach so messing with reflection is no longer necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand the problem - upcasting is normally not needed.
but it seams like the problem is to get the *upper* class of the object,
if use the `getSuperclass` method:

```
    Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(iViewClass.getSuperclass());
```

Documentation: [getSuperclass()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29)